# Link tracking with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to make some link tracking/partnership system for a client. It should detect link click on a site where my javascript is included, count a click and then redirect to a link from href and then check some user actions on target page. Have you got any references, links, tutorials, book' titles which may be helpful ?

Comment: [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/).

Answer (score 0):

A common practice is to let your javascript load a tracking pixel before redirecting to the link url goal. This pixel allows you to set cookies as well if you want to track it further after the client has left your page.